# Stuck installing on win 8 laptop

Tags: windows-8

I can get to the Ubuntu screen, and installation begins....and then while it seems like everything is installing, everything starts to be removed and uninstalled. Using a liveUSB, and laptop preloaded w/ windows 8. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

P.s- I can run in trial mode...

Comment: Check this answer buddy: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: That's the tutorial that I used :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the md5hash of the Ubuntu .iso file is the same as it appears.

`-7b7c56c74008da7d97bd49669c8a045d *ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
7ad57cadae955bd04019389d4b9c1dcb *ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso
3af0638f69d15d61d813d14fddc9df6e *ubuntu-12.10-desktop-armhf+omap4.img
b4191c1d1d6fdf358c154f8bf86b97dd *ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso`

If your .iso file does not have an hash code like that then just download a new one and make another bootable CD/USB.    Usually that is the case..

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the hash code- I used the "how to create a bootable USB stick on windows" - and downloaded the iso....Ubuntu 12.10 desktop.

Comment: It may have something to do with this- "If there is a problem, then try to create a small partition (About 250 MB of size) for the EFI part of the system. This is done in the installation part where it asks you if you want to install on a desired partition or used the Advanced Options. Select the advanced options if you come up with a problem. In there, create a 250 MB partition for EFI and the rest for GRUB and other stuff you are accustomed to."-           Is there a step by step on how to create this partition?

Comment: You can use WinMD5Free, a freeware utility, to calculate the MD5 of a file.  See http://www.winmd5.com/.